# Efficient Algorithm For Generating Sub-sequences

Tags: arrays

Most of the naive algorithms for generating the subsequences in an array are of Complexity around O(2*n*n).
Generally this breaks down when applied in large scale scenarios. So is there a better and faster algorithm to generate the subsequences in an array efficiently ?

Comment: Are you sure you meant to ask this question? There are O(n^2) subsequences of an array of length n. I don't think you'll find an algorithm that produces each one in less than constant time.

Comment: Not constant time...but what is the fastest algorithm that produces it ?

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make sense. There are O(n^2) subsequences. You can't enumerate each one in less than constant time. Therefore O(n^2) is the fastest possible algorithm. Your question has no answer.  (Incidentally, O(2 n^2) is the same as O(n^2).)

Comment: Note that I'm assuming you're talking about contiguous subsequences. If you're asking about general subsequences, then the number of subsequences is O(n^(n/2)), which is _much_ bigger.